# What is the difference between Terminated#actor() and Terminated#getActor()

Tags: java, scala, akka

I simply want to know the actor of the `Terminated` message another actor received, to be sure to handle the message only if the "right" actor was terminated. The `Terminated` class has two methods to tell me that, what is the difference between them? I can't read Scala yet, so looking up the source hasn't helped me. The methods are not documented with JavaDoc.

```
Terminated terminated = (Terminated)message;
terminated.actor(); // what is this?
terminated.getActor(); // what is that?
```

Help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. `actor` is simply the Scala property, whereas `getActor` is the corresponding Java accessor.

You can see it in the signature of the class:

```
final case class Terminated private[akka] (@BeanProperty actor: ActorRef)
```

The `@BeanProperty` annotation is a special Scala one that generates accessors and mutators (`getX`/`setX`) for Java bean compatibility.